# Why Size is different for different pointers

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define R 10
#define C 20

int main()
{
    int *p;
    int *p1[R];
    int *p2[R][C];
    printf("%d %d %d", sizeof(*p),sizeof(*p1),sizeof(*p2));
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the output: `4 8 160`? Why does size of `p1` becomes 8 and not 4?

Comment: use `%zu` to print a _size_t_.

Comment: in visuals studio 2013 its 4 4 80

Comment: Note that `*p` is **not** a pointer: it's an `int`.

Comment: compile with all warnings enabled.   The posted code does not cleanly compile.  All the compiler raised warnings are on the printf() parameters.  Fix the warnings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the *types*.

1. `sizeof(*p)` ==> `sizeof(int)`
2. `sizeof(*p1)` ==> `sizeof(int *)`
3. `sizeof(*p2)` ==> `sizeof((int [20]))`

Note: Depending on your platform and compiler, you'll get different results.

Also, as we know, `sizeof` produces a result of type `size_t`, it's advised to use `%zu` format specifier to print the result.